# How to fix NEO4J docker container - service unavailable error - could not perform discovery?

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am trying to make a neo4j container work using the command below. The command was adjusted from the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/).

```
    docker run --detach \
      -p7474:7474 \
      -p7687:7687 \
      -v $HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
      -v $HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
      -v $HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
      --env NEO4J_AUTH=none \
       neo4j
```

When the container starts, I am trying to interact with the database via the browser UI (http://localhost:7474).

The issue is that when I try to perform database related actions I get a ServiceUnavailable error (after minutes of waiting) with the message:

```
Could not perform discovery. No routing servers available. Known routing table: RoutingTable[database=default database, expirationTime=0, currentTime=1583932006016, routers=[], readers=[], writers=[]]
```

This happens for any cypher statement I run. For example:

```
MATCH (n)
```

I've searched for solutions for this error, but none seems applicable (as most relate to cluster setup or calling neo4j services externally).

From the conf file I could not find anything which might help (where the only change I performed was uncommenting:

```
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
```

**Question:** How can I fix this issue so that I can interact with the database via the neo4j interface?

Any input is much apreciated.

Comment: Try changing the protocol from neo4j to bolt. https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/516

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are pointing to your correct and complete folder locations....

e.g -v $HOME/neo4j/data:/Users/xxx/Downloads/data

Comment: I checked and the paths are correct. Still does not work.